Efficiently Visualizing and Retrieval Ethereum Smart Contract Events on Decentralized Storage
I want to know what are the recommended decentralized storage solutions (IPFS or sub-graph)? and general process for retrieving them for front-end visualization?

I've noticed many reputable protocols like Uniswap, Aave, etc. utilising Graph for retrieving and visualizing events data. Using that, they access large amounts of data in real-time through various GraphQL queries, taking advantage of its powerful filtering capabilities.
